# How do you escape a $ character in pweave?

Tags: pweave

I'm using pweave to write an HTML document. I would like to express a $ sign in text, for example:

> Bob has $1, Sally has $2

However pweave thinks that `1, Sally has` should be formatted as maths. If I use `\$` then it stops the math environment but keeps the `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me, but `Bob has $1, Sally has$ 2` doesn't work...

You could try `{\$}`, `\{\$\}`, `\textdollar` or `$\textdollar$`.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML output at least, `&#32;` produces a $ without the junk. Unsure of the fix if targeting LaTeX.

Comment: Good to know, although I'm not writing a latex document at the moment. I've updated the question to reflect that. The bounty was placed before I found this solution obviously, but the bounty is there and I can't remove it.

Comment: Yeah, bounties can't be removed. You can either award the bounty to someone or let it vanish.